# Fatal error while trying to save to SQLite db

Tags: php, sql, database, arrays, sqlite

I'm trying to save data from nodes in a xml doc that's loaded into the app with SimpleXML. Below is my code, but something is wrong with the SQL statement because I get a fatal error.

I can't get why this is thrown because *id* (as referred in the error message below) is used as a value to be put in, not as a column.

So, what am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

**php:**

```
    $db;

    $theProducers = simplexml_load_file('sources/producers.xml');

    foreach ($theProducers->producer as $producer) {
        $attr = $producer->attributes();
        $producers[$i]['id'] = (int)$attr[0];
        $producers[$i]['name'] = (string)$producer->name;
        $producers[$i]['address'] = (string)$producer->address;
        $producers[$i]['zipcode'] = (string)$producer->zipcode;
        $producers[$i]['town'] = (string)$producer->town;
        $producers[$i]['url'] = (string)$producer->url;
        $producers[$i]['imgurl'] = (string)$producer->imgurl;

        $i += 1;
    }

    try {
            $db = new PDO('sqlite:ProducersDB.sqlite');
            $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        die("Something went wrong: " . $e->getMessage());
    }

    for($i = 0; $i < count($producers); $i++) {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO producers (producerid, name, address, zipcode, town, url, imgurl)
                VALUES($producers[$i]['id'], $producers[$i]['name'], $producers[$i]['address'], $producers[$i]['zipcode'], $producers[$i]['town'], $producers[$i]['url'], $producers[$i]['imgurl']); ";

        if(!$db->query($sql)) {
            die("Couln't execute query!");
        }
    }
```

**error message:**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]:
General error: 1 no such column: 'id'' in
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/app/index.php:55 Stack trace: #0
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/app/Labb2/index.php(55):
PDO->query('INSERT INTO pro...') #1 {main} thrown in
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/app/index.php on line 55
```

**db structure:**

```
Table: Producers

id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
producerid INT,
name TEXT,
address TEXT,
zipcode INT,
town TEXT,
url TEXT,
imgurl TEXT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [string parsing documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing), multidimensional arrays require that you use the complex syntax; also, SQL strings must be quoted:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO producers (...)
        VALUES({$producers[$i]['id']}, '{$producers[$i]['name']}', ..."
```

To avoid string formatting problems, it is recommended to use [parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3stmt.bindvalue.php).

Answer (score 1):

You query to INSERT element in your table is not properly built. Your values are in a PHP array which is not interpreted properly between your double quotes, it should be something like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO producers(producerid, name)
        VALUES ('" . $producers[$i]['id'] . "', '" . $producers[$i]['name'] . "')";
```

You should also look the method [prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) from PDO to properly set dynamic values in your query instead of building it by yourself.

**EDIT**: according to the PHP documentation on [Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) I'm wrong and you can interpret an array between double quotes, sorry for the confusion.